limit permutation outputs
I've developed a function that generates permutations from a vector vec, with the option to limit the number of outputs. I want to ensure that no value appears more than 3 times in the same position.
This function generate_permutations generates permutations of length longitud_permutaciones from the vec. It then filters these permutations to ensure that no element repeats more than 3 times in the same position. If the number of resulting permutations exceeds cantidad_resultados, it returns only the specified number of permutations.
library(combinat)
library(gtools)
generate_permutations <- function(vec, permutation_length, result_count) {
    # Get all unique permutations of the specified length
    permutations <- permutations(length(vec), permutation_length, vec)
    
    # Filter permutations to ensure no element repeats more than 3 times in the same position
    filtered_permutations <- permutations[rowSums(matrix(permutations, ncol = permutation_length)      == rep(vec, each = permutation_length)) <= 3, ]
    
    # Show only the specified number of results if it's less than the total
    if (result_count < nrow(filtered_permutations)) {
        filtered_permutations <- filtered_permutations[1: result_count, ]
    }
    
    return(filtered_permutations)
}

# Example usage
vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
permutation_length <- 3
result_count <- 5  # Change this value as needed

result <- generate_permutations(vec, permutation_length, result_count)
print(result)

Here's the breakdown:
Input Parameters:
vec: The vector from which permutations are generated.
longitud_permutaciones: The length of each permutation.
cantidad_resultados: The desired number of resulting permutations.
Generating Permutations:
It uses the permutations function from the gtools package to generate all unique permutations of length longitud_permutaciones from vec.
Filtering Permutations:
It then filters these permutations to ensure that no element repeats more than 3 times in the same position. This is done by checking the count of each element in each position of the permutations.
Limiting Results:
If the total number of resulting permutations exceeds cantidad_resultados, it only returns the first cantidad_resultados permutations.
Output:
It returns the filtered permutations as the result.
This function provides a way to generate and filter permutations based on specific constraints, ensuring that the resulting permutations meet the criteria specified.
I did the following
# Filter the permutations to ensure that no element repeats more than 3 times in the same position
filtered_permutations <- permutations[rowSums(apply(permutations, 1, function(row) {
    table(row) <= 3
})) == permutation_length, ]

We want to filter the permutations to ensure that no element repeats more than 3 times in the same position.
We use apply() function to apply a function to each row of the permutations matrix.
Inside the function, table(row) <= 3 counts the occurrences of each element in the row and checks if any element occurs more than 3 times.
rowSums() then sums up the results for each row, indicating how many elements violate the constraint.
We compare this sum to permutation_length to ensure that all elements meet the constraint for each permutation.
Permutations that meet the constraint are retained, while those that do not are filtered out.
   [,1] [,2] [,3]

\[1,\]    1    2    3
\[2,\]    1    2    4
\[3,\]    1    3    2
\[4,\]    1    3    4
\[5,\]    1    4    2

The output I need to obtain is the following, for example, no number is repeated more than 3 times in the same position.
1 2 3
1 3 2
1 4 2
2 1 4
2 3 4

The requirement is that no value should appear more than 3 times in the output. To clarify, this will be useful for designing conjoint scenarios.

permutations is not a base R function. When using functions that are not base R functions please start the scripts with a call to library(pkgname) in order to load the packages needed.

Could you give a different example? As it stands, it looks like your filtered output is exactly the same as gtools::permutations only subsetted to the first 5 results. Also as @RuiBarradas pointed out, make sure to have all libraries clearly indicated in your code.

@JoséMadera I require the filtering of permutations, ensuring that no more than 3 permutations exhibit the same values in identical positions. In the provided example, the value '1' occurs 5 times in the same position, which is incorrect. I need to limit its occurrence to at most 3 times.

@GenesisGuadalupeJimnez Avoid using function names as object names, in this case vector. Check ?vector beforehand to see if it's free. I've edited that in your question.

You could split !x by x, replace first n values with TRUE, unsplit along original x and subset the permutation matrix.
> sub_prmt <- \(v, len, n) {
+   prmt <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(v, len)
+   slc <- \(x, n) {
+     split(!x, x) |> 
+       lapply(replace, seq_len(n), TRUE) |>
+       unsplit(x)
+   }
+   matrix(prmt[apply(prmt, 2, slc, n=n)], ncol=ncol(prmt))
+ }
>
> (res <- sub_prmt(vec, perm_len, res_count))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    4
 [3,]    1    3    2
 [4,]    2    3    4
 [5,]    2    4    2
 [6,]    2    4    3
 [7,]    3    1    3
 [8,]    3    1    4
 [9,]    3    3    1
[10,]    4    4    1
[11,]    4    1    2
[12,]    4    2    1

Check result:
> apply(res, 2, tabulate)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3
[4,]    3    3    3

Using RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral, think it's faster.

Data:
vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
perm_len <- 3
res_count <- 3

